# Search by mutiple fields , SELECT IN (everything)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to search some products and get results . 
This is my PHP code:

```
function Item_Search($AppID, $Keyword = '', $Wears)
{
    // expected $Wears = [1,0,1,0,1] , numbers can be diffrent from 0 to 1

    $WearNames = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black'];
    $FinalWear = [];

    foreach ($Wears as $i => $Wear) {
        if ($Wear == 1) {
            $FinalWear[] = $WearNames[$i];
        }
    }
    $FinalWear = json_encode($FinalWear);
    $FinalWear = str_replace(str_split('[]'), '', $FinalWear);

$ItemList = Query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE appid=$AppID 
AND name LIKE '%$Keyword%'
AND wear IN ($FinalWear)
");
}
```

This code works just fine, but there are some products without any color . In this case I want to say if all colors were 1 (true), then show products without color too.

So my question is, can I put something as `$FinalWear` in `wear IN ($FinalWear)` so I can get all the results?

Comment: When you say `without any color` does this mean that the column `wear` is `NULL` or an empty string `''`?

Comment: @Nick wear is empty , I think it means `' '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the sum of the elements in `$Wear` and if it is the same as the count, then all elements are set. You can then use this to add an `OR` condition to the `wear` test, checking for an empty string in `wear` when all elements in `$Wear` are set:

```
function Item_Search($AppID, $Keyword = '', $Wears)
{
    // expected $Wears = [1,0,1,0,1] , numbers can be different from 0 to 1

    $WearNames = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black'];
    $FinalWear = [];

    foreach ($Wears as $i => $Wear) {
        if ($Wear == 1) {
            $FinalWear[] = $WearNames[$i];
        }
    }
    $FinalWear = "'" . implode("','", $FinalWear) . "'";
    $EmptyWear = array_sum($Wears) == count($Wears) ? "OR wear = ''" : '';

    $ItemList = Query(<<<EOD
SELECT * 
FROM items 
WHERE appid=$AppID 
  AND name LIKE '%$Keyword%'
  AND (wear IN ($FinalWear) $EmptyWear)
EOD
);
}
```

Demo (of query output) on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/DigL7)

Note that if `$AppID` and `$Keyword` come from outside sources your query is vulnerable to SQL injection, and you should use a prepared statement to avoid that possibility. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

If `wear` being empty means that it is actually `NULL`, change the line generating `$EmptyWear` to

```
 $EmptyWear = array_sum($Wears) == count($Wears) ? "OR wear IS NULL" : '';
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for , thanks . and I have mysqli_escape_string in my code , but i wanted to make the question as small as possible .